# Vim "gq" command doesn't recognize Haskell-style comments

Tags: visual-mode, formatting, comments

I have a Haskell file on VIM with a Haskell-style comment block:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uKS2.png]

When I select that comment block on visual mode...

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFHWf.png]

And press `gq`, I expected VIM to format my comment to something like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nsgT.png]

But instead, this is what VIM does:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qn2Dw.png]

How can I fix it?

Comment: It works on my gVim (version 7.4-798). What's the result of running `:set ft?` and `:set comments?`. What's your Vim version? Do you have `:filetype plugin indent on` in your vimrc ?

Comment: I don't have that, VanLaser. I actually have `"filetype plugin on
` commented, I recall actively doing so for some reason I don't remember. `set ft?` gives `haskell`, and `set comments` gives `comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://,b:#,:%,:XCOMM,n:>,fb:-` (before Lithis's answer).

Comment: Yes, no wonder the comments aren't recognized ... :)

Comment: Okay I see the `filetype plugin` is what VIM uses for filetype based comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:set comments+=:--`

This appends `:--` to the value of [`comments`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27comments%27), which adds `--` as a comment line indicator. The format of this option is described by [`:help format-comments`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#format-comments).

Comment: The question is, I guess, why isn't it already there, in OP case?

Comment: @VanLaser I don't know, maybe my vimrc or existing plugins messed with it (if it was supposed to?) It solves the issue, though. Thank you all!