# visual mode gq not reflowing comment block

Tags: visual-mode, formatting, comments

I am looking for an easy way to reflow blocks of comments (in GO).  According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435808/reflowing-comment-blocks-with-vim) I should be able to just run `gq` on a block and it will reflow automatically, but this doesn't seem to work.

Here is some sample text:

```
// PrintStarredRepos tries to print tags of repo's that have been starred
// adaf da df a da fs daf e according to the "user" configuration setting that is read in from the
// config file.
```

And this is what the text looks like after I run `gq` on it.

```
// PrintStarredRepos tries to print tags of repo's that have been starred //
adaf da df a da fs daf e according to the "user" configuration setting that is
read in from the // config file.
```

Here are relevant settings in my vimrc based on details I found in [another post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4251/vim-gq-command-doesnt-recognize-haskell-style-comments#).

- textwidth=80
- filetype plugin indent on
- set ft?  (filetype=go)
- set comments? (comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://)

I can't figure out why comments aren't wrapping?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my vimrc file I had `set paste` turned on.

When I removed this configuration I was able to get comments to flow correctly.

Comment: If you `set paste` often (a very useful feature), don't forget to undo this with `set nopaste` once you have finished pasting. `set paste`, I've noticed, introduces some surprising side effects.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check your `formatoptions` setting. According to the [manual](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#fo-table) you need the "q" flag to be present:

```
                                                        *fo-table*
You can use the 'formatoptions' option  to influence how Vim formats text.
'formatoptions' is a string that can contain any of the letters below.  The
default setting is "tcq".  You can separate the option letters with commas for
readability.

letter   meaning when present in 'formatoptions'
[...]
q   Allow formatting of comments with "gq".
    Note that formatting will not change blank lines or lines containing
    only the comment leader.  A new paragraph starts after such a line,
    or when the comment leader changes.
```