# Wrapping comment in visual mode not working with gq

Tags: neovim

I'm using neovim. When I visually select a comment in Python that is longer than my textwidth setting, and press `gq`, it does not wrap the comment.

I've looked at this question: [visual mode gq not reflowing comment block](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5594/visual-mode-gq-not-reflowing-comment-block), however my `formatoptions` setting looks correct:

```
set formatoptions=cjoqrt
```

What is causing this to not work?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Check out [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) and try to post a minimal set of instructions that demonstrates the problem

Comment: In the most recent versions of Neovim, `formatexpr` is set to `v:lua.vim.lsp.formatexpr()`. This makes Neovim use a language server to format, also with `gq`. I don't how how to preserve that and also be able to wrap text with `gq`. You can `:set formatexpr=` to just get the wrapping.

Comment: Thanks! `:set formatexpr=` made `gq` work again. Although I'm curious, what else might I be losing by un-setting `formatexpr`?

Comment: Also seems to have suddenly stopped working for me, and also fixed by `:set formatexpr=`.

Comment: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/19677

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As mentioned by @cassava, your problem may be due to [this PR](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/19677), which changes `formatexpr` to take its initial value from the LSP (as I understand it).

There are a few suggestions for workarounds in [this issue](https://github.com/jose-elias-alvarez/null-ls.nvim/issues/1131), linked to from [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/zalqgc/gq_and_formatexpr_weirdness/), of which using `gw` instead of `gq` seems like the easiest one-off workaround, and this snippet works for me for a more robust approach:

```lua
-- Use internal formatting for bindings like gq. 
 vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd('LspAttach', { 
   callback = function(args) 
     vim.bo[args.buf].formatexpr = nil 
   end, 
 })
```

Alternatively, I am using the below to restore the prior behavior specifically for Python / pylsp:

```lua
local pylsp_on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
  default_lsp_on_attach(client, bufnr)
  -- Restore gqq
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(bufnr, "formatexpr", "")
end

nvim_lsp.pylsp.setup({
-- ...
  on_attach = pylsp_on_attach,
-- ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know `:gw` was thing (`:gq` was baked into my brain for years). That worked for me!

Comment: For whatever reason `:gw` doesn't work for me either. @n8henrie do you mind adding some comments around what each of the two snippets you've listed actually does and why they fix the underlying issue?

The first one reads like it just disables using LSP for formatting to restore `:gq` behavior. Is that correct?

Comment: @ffledgling the comment above explains it, if not well -- yes it disables LSP formatting so that you can use neovim's formatting, for the buffer in question.